# Is there a away to check if one nvarchar is less than the other?

Tags: c#, string, numeric

I have two values that are string but they hold numeric data. I would use convert.toint32 however I am passing a string through to the database and therefore will cause confliction (returning the value based on a query). Is there a way to check if numerical string 'values' are less than another without converting (i don't mean length)?

I mean if the NUMERIC data in the string is LESS THAN the other NUMERIC data in the OTHER string (it is a nvarchar not an int). The field in the database uses string not int

Comment: If your `varchar` fields only hold numeric data, why are they `varchar` and not `int` or similar field?

Comment: you will have to convert it to number/int/ or any numeric datatype to check if it is less than or greater than the other value.. strings cannot be checked directly without converting to number.

Comment: please post some code to elaborate your question...

Comment: If they are both non-negative integers, you could perhaps zero-pad on the left... but frankly I'd just to the conversion.

Comment: forget it no one seems to understand

Comment: How are you returning the data from the database?

Comment: Are you saying that the reason you can't parse the string and compare is because you want to return one string back to the database? If so, just parse them to compare, but return the original string, or do `.ToString()`

Comment: Always on this sort of position's you will end writing a Complex Algorithm which will take more time than the usual one's to do that simple task.

Comment: If there are 5 people failing to understand 1 person's question, I would suggest that the one person should add to their question rather than complain about the 5 people.

Comment: Converting String, to int and comparing is just overhead, user int only if possible

Answer (score 1):

First question I have is why are you not using an `int` field type in SQL for storing integer values? Seems like a lot of overhead using an `nvarchar` to me

As for comparing them in the database, you could use the sql `CONVERT` function and convert them to `int`

psuedo code...  you'll have to fashion your correct sql select statement around this

```
IF CONVERT(INT, @parameter) < CONVERT(INT, field_value)
BEGIN
  -- Do something
END
```